# Leaflet: Close Popup when the markers cluster

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I have markers and when that markers are near to each other, it will cluster when i zoom it out. I also have a popup whenever the details of markers in the sidebar is clicked. i have this code for the zooming:

```
$("#mapContainer").on("click",".zoomMarker",function(){ 
    var zoom;
    var no = $(this).attr("mapNo");
    var deviceID = $(this).attr("deviceID");
    console.log("eventData : ",findMapNo(no).eventData);

    var events = findMapNo(no).eventData[deviceID].events;

    //console.log("events: ",events);
    if( events.length>0 ){
        var eventsIndex = findMapNo(no).eventData[deviceID].events.length-1;
        var temp_content = createPopupContent(deviceID, eventsIndex, no);

        var lat = events[events.length-1][4];
        var lng = events[events.length-1][3];
        var latLng = new L.latLng(lat, lng);

        var setZoom = findMapNo(no).map.setZoom(20);
        findMapNo(no).map.panTo(latLng); 

        var Oldzoom = findMapNo(no).map.getZoom();

        popup = L.popup({
            permanent: true,
            autoPan: false,
            minWidth: 200,
            closeOnClick: true,
            minHeight: 200,
            offset: [0, -12]})
            .setLatLng(latLng)
            .setContent(temp_content);

        if(Oldzoom == Oldzoom){ //the first default zoom
            findMapNo(no).map.removeLayer(markersCluster);
            findMapNo(no).map.addLayer(markersLayer);

            if(findMapNo(no).map.hasLayer(markersLayer)){
                console.log("there is marker!! Oldzoom");
                findMapNo(no).map.openPopup(popup);
            }

        }

        findMapNo(no).map.on("zoomend", function (e) {
            zoom = this.getZoom();

            if(zoom != Oldzoom){ 
                findMapNo(no).map.removeLayer(markersLayer); //remove marker
                findMapNo(no).map.addLayer(markersCluster); //cluster the near markers
                findMapNo(no).map.closePopup(popup); // must close the popup when marker is cluster
            }else{
                findMapNo(no).map.removeLayer(markersCluster);
                findMapNo(no).map.addLayer(markersLayer);
            }
            return;
        });
    }else{
        toaster("Marker No Location","warning");
    }
});
```

my problem is when i zoom it out, when i click another marker (name of the marker) in the sidebar, the right data of the clicked marker is in the console, but the map is staying in the last click marker.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Is it working? `closePopup()` is the only offical way to close the popup. https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#popup-closepopup

Comment: @FalkeDesign its working but whenever izoom it out and clicked another markers (details) in the sidebar, the data of the clicked marker is in the console,  but the old clicked marker is still in the map... i will edit this post and put the code of the whole click function.

Comment: Can you pls add a screenshot and have you a online version?